# i have a problem with ASP.NET Core to share between model and view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In my project I have a login and I want the username to be usable in the `.cshtml`.

I have it in ASP.NET Core MVC mode and these are my files:

`LoginModel.cs`

```
namespace MVC_Catálogo_Imágenes.Models
{
 public class LoginModel
 {
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obligatorio")]
  public string? User { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obligatorio")]
  public string? Password { get; set; }
 }
}
```

`Controller.cs`:

```
public ActionResult Login()
{            
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel l)
{
 try
 {
  using (SqlConnection con = new(_contexto.Valor))
  {
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new("sp_login", con))
   {
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Usuario", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = l.User;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = l.Password;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Estado", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
    con.Open();
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    int count = result == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(result);
    con.Close();

    if (count > 0)
    {
      IsAuthenticated = true;
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
      ViewData["error"] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos";
      return View();
    }
   }
  }
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
  ViewData["error2"] = "Ha habido un error al iniciar sesión";
  return View();
 }
}
```

`Profile.cshtml`

```
@model LoginModel
<h5>@Model.User</h5>
```

Well, when calling the model from the view, I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get devolvió null.

Comment: `@Model` is NULL. You should do `return View(new LoginModel());`

Comment: What do you pass from your Profile action to Profile.cshtml ?  "a login and I want the username to be usable in the .cshtml." do you mean  Profile.cshtml  is Login.cshtml  ?

Comment: @Chetan That doesn't work for me, I tried this:

public ActionResult Login(LoginModel l)
{
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", l);
}

public ActionResult Profile()
{
   return View(l);
}

Comment: @QingGuo 
In the profile action I return this:
public ActionResult Profile()
{
   return View(new LoginModel());
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(lambdar)

i fixed using cookies:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel loginModel)
{
  Response.Cookies.Append("un", loginModel.User);
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

public ActionResult Profile()
{
  var model = new LoginModel
  {
      User = Request.Cookies["un"]
  };
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Hi, no. That is a temporary solution. The redirect to profile does it fine, but the path is still "account/login" and if I go to "account/profile" @model returns to null again

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel l)
{
  // ...
  return View("Profile",l);
}
public ActionResult Profile(LoginModel l)
{
   return View(l);
}

Comment: @lmbdr How do you go to account/profile ? by  `return RedirectToAction` in Login action or ?

Comment: @lmbdr Do you want something like my update ?

Comment: I access the profile from a button in the _Layout.cshtml view.
<a type="button" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Profile">Profile</a>

In my Controller:
public ActionResult Profile(LoginModel l)
{
    return View(l);
}
Here the value of the User variable of the model is null, it is not saved after doing the login

Comment: @lmbdr Do you want this :   https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgJWD.gif ?

Comment: Yeah! but that the login redirects to Home/Index if it is valid and then when accessing the profile it can collect the user's name, or from any view using the correct @Model

Comment: @lmbdr  Please have a look at my update.

Comment: Great... I installed the NewtonSoft.Json package to be able to use JsonConvert, all good until I exit profile view and back in
i get this error:
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name'

in this line:
var l = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginModel>((string)TempData["l"]);

Comment: @lmbdr Ok , there is another way, how about  try to get the user data from your databse in your  `Profile()` ?

Comment: I don't know any other way to get the user from the database other than through @Model.User

Comment: @lmbdr How about use Session?

Comment: I don't know that tool

Comment: @lmbdr Have a look at my answer and [session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: I get this error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SessionExtensions.GetString(...) return null.


In Profile.cshtml:
(at)model LoginModel
(at)using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
(at)inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
// in this line
<h5>(at)HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("User").ToUpper()</h5>

Comment: I have managed to solve it!

Comment: Hi @QingGuo I have changed your answer with what I used to fix the error and have marked it as accepted